# Should there be a tag about the Himalayas?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Now, I understand there is a tag about Mountains, but people use the Himalayas as an example a lot, and **people ask about the Indian-Eurasian plate collision every once in a while.** I'm taking the Community's Advice if there should be a tag called "The-Himalayas".

For example

- [Indian-Eurasian plate](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=Indian-Eurasian+plate) returns 24 posts
- [Himalayas](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=Himalayas) returns 76 posts.

**note:** There is already a [tibetan-plateau](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tibetan-plateau) tag that uses 8 posts.

Comment: When recommending something or asking if something is needed, it's very helpful to include examples, so I've added a few as a start. Welcome to edit or add more. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick search on other tags on the site, it seems that "place" tags are pretty sparse.  I see tags being used for bodies of water like oceans, and I see some land masses  like continents and "greenland".  If we introduce a tag for the Himalayas, it would seem that many places could also be added (e.g. Sahara, Hawaii, Australia, Africa, Andes, Alps, etc.), so it could potentially be a slippery slope.  Personally I don't have a problem with adding more tags, but many users think they should be cleaned up.  I think adding the Himalayas would be fine.  We just have to be sure we are adding geographic places, not political places.  For instance, Mediterranean is a current tag, but "Germany" was deleted.  I agree with this idea and think we should delete tags like "California" but keep tags like "Greenland".  Here is a post that discusses this more: [Should we clean up the tags on this site?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/should-we-clean-up-the-tags-on-this-site/1542#1542)

Comment: `+1` This seems like a well-reasoned summary; Himalayas (might be) fine but caution should be exercised and political places avoided as site policy per the linked meta. Also folks **please remember to up (down) vote on meta posts** so that good (bad) ideas can be taken (not taken) as a community viewpoint. For example, **so far I'm the only person to actually up vote [getting rid of political place names](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1542/6031)!**

Comment: **note:** There is already a [tag:tibetan-plateau] tag that uses 8 posts.

Comment: Germany is a political Region/state but the Himalayas is a geographical region, Tibetan-plateau is a larger area INCLUDING the Himalayas, but people often refer to the Himalayas as an example.