# New tag for tipping-point and metastability

Tags: discussion

While searching for questions (e.g. [1](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/15423), [2](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/10503)) on the topics of *metastability* and *tipping-points*, in the context of environmental systems, I noticed that tags related to these fundamental concepts are lacking.

Although I am aware there has been [discussion about the number of tags](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/should-we-clean-up-the-tags-on-this-site) on this site, it seems to me that the fundamental [concepts](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/eme504/node/583) of `metastability` and `tipping-point` are sufficiently important to the environmental sciences to warrant their own tag.

Perhaps a `metastability` tag with related concepts such as `tipping-point` and `multistability` mentioned in the description?

(I don't have sufficient reputation to create tags myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Environmental sciences are far away from my area of expertise, so I will let others decide if the proposed tags would be pertinent additions to the site.

However, I'd like to point out that the concept of *metastability* is also widely used in geology, specifically when talking about mineral assemblages which persist under conditions that are different from their thermodynamical stable domain. Actually, looking for "metastable" on the site yields two results where the term is used with this meaning: [#1](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/8849/18081), [#2](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/14502/18081). So, if we were to introduce the tag, we would need to make its meaning unambiguous.

Comment: You are right, it should be unambiguous. However, I'm just wondering (please excuse my ignorance): Is there really a difference between the concept of metastability as used in geology, and that used in environmental sciences? Or is it the same phenomenon arising in a different context?